# Zend Framework 2 - How to skip validation of Zend\Form\Element\Time if empty

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a way to skip validation for a time field so I can just enter NULL into the database, if there is no start time ?

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'start_time',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Time',
    'attributes' => array(
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Start Time',
        'format' => 'H:i',
    )
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the **"required = false"** & **"allow_empty = true"** in your input filters.

Comment: $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'start_time',
        'required'   => false,
        'allow_empty' => true
    ));